# Vue v-links in JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, vue.js, vue-router

I am relatively new to Vue, so forgive me if this is obvious (or obviously impossible).

I have a set of JSON data (fetched from a RESTful API via vue-resource):

`{content: "This is content. <a href='/blog'> Link to blog </a>"}`

Right now, the link triggers a page reload. If it were a vue-router `v-link`, that would not be an issue. However, this doesn't work (quotes are escaped in the data, of course):

`{content: "This is content. <a v-link="{ path: '/blog' }"> Link to blog </a>"}`

At this point, the template is already parsed, and Vue won't create a v-link anymore (it will just show up as a v-link in the rendered html).

My final result would ideally mean that I could include links in my CMS, either in HTML or Vue format, and have Vue route them correctly as v-links.

Is there something I can do to make Vue interpret the link in the JSON data?

Comment: Check this issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/48

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. Not sure how I missed it. I'm having trouble implementing it though... Where does it go? Also, it seems that $compile is what makes it happen. Could $compile be run on a parent element? I can't get it to work, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've answered the question on [Vue Chat](https://gitter.im/vuejs/vue), and writing it here in case any other people facing similar problem

Simplified example on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/nandiin/pen/wWaLbp?editors=1010)

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <a v-link= "{path:'/home'}">Go to home</a>
  </div>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
<template id="home">
  <div>
    <div>
      Fetched Content:
    </div>
    <div>
      {{{ fetchedContent }}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<template id="route1">
  <div>
    Route1 view
  </div>
</template>
<template id="route2">
  <div>
    Route2 view, this is different from Route1
  </div>
</template>
```

javascript

```
function getContent (callback) {
  var content = 'Click this: <a href="/route1">Go to route1</a> and <a href="/route2">Go to route2</a>'
  setTimeout(function () { callback(content) }, 1000)
}
var Home = Vue.component('home',{
  template:'#home',
  data: function () {
    return {
      fetchedContent: 'Loading...'
    };
  },
  ready: function () {
    var self = this
    var router = this.$router

    getContent( function (result) {
      self.fetchedContent = result;
      Vue.nextTick(function () {
        var hyperLinks = self.$el.getElementsByTagName('a')
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(hyperLinks, function (a) {
          a.onclick = function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault()
            router.go({ path: a.getAttribute("href") })
          }
        })
      })
    })
  }
});
var Route1 = Vue.component('route1', {
  template: '#route1'
});
var Route2 = Vue.component('route2', {
  template: "#route2"
});
var router = new VueRouter({
    hashbang:false,
    history:true
});
router.map({
    '/home':{
      component:Home
    },
    '/route1':{
      component:Route1
    },
    '/route2':{
      component:Route2
    }
});
router.start({
}, '#app');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar solution here: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56802857/laravel-eloquent-data-or-simple-props-to-create-a-custom-vue-router-link-in-vue/56809186#56809186) using a custom dataset in my JSON code and a click listener to process it:

```
mounted() {
window.addEventListener('click', event => {
    let target = event.target
    if (target && target.href && target.dataset.url) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(target.dataset.url);
       const url = JSON.parse(target.dataset.url);
        console.log(url.name)
       this.$router.push(url.name);
    } 
});
```

},