# Laravel eloquent data or simple props to create a custom Vue-router link in Vue.Js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, vue-router

I have a SPA made in VUE and Laravel.

Laravel returns API request and VUE create the frontend using the received data.

In a few cases, I have some HTML code returned as compiled data by API engine having links inside.

I would like to use these links in vue router but if I return the API having code like this:

**JSON code**

```
{
    comment: {
        'bla <strong>bla</strong> bla <router-link :to="name:\'page\'">text</router-link>'
    }
}
```

Then I use the JSON code in my component template like:

```
<div v-html={comment}></div>
```

But this is not rendered and returned as plain HTML: I see the **bold** but not the `<a href='page'>text...` as I need but I got `<router-link...` as plain text.

**Simple JSFiddle test**

Here [a demo test](https://jsfiddle.net/uncoke/92x0jhr1/) where I try to replicate the issue. If you click on Foo Link (Top menu) it open a component having props data with HTML code inside. The bold is shown properly but the router link is not rendered

```
data: {
    msg: 'Hello World',
    comment : '<div class="comment">This is a <strong>bold</strong> <br> 
               this should be a <router-link :to="{\'name\':\'home\'}">
               router link</router-link></div>'
        }
```

[image]

How can I force the vue-router render in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by my own: https://jsfiddle.net/uncoke/92x0jhr1/

**Here my own fix**:

The custom data with link:

```
    { team: "<a href=\"/club/"+team.id+"\" data-to='{\"name\": \"team\",\"params\":{\"teamId\":"+ team.id+"}}'>"+ team.team+"</a> "+userCode,
 ....}
```

**The click Listener**

```
mounted() {
        window.addEventListener('click', event => {
            let target = event.target;
            if (target && target.href && target.dataset.to) {
                event.preventDefault();
                const url = JSON.parse(target.dataset.to);
                //router.push({ name: 'user', params: { userId: '123' } })
                this.$router.push(url);
            }
        });
    }
```